# Create VPN Connection with NEVPNManager Swift 2.0 in OSX

Tags: swift

I want do create in SWIFT 2.0 (Xcode 7.1, OSX 10.10) a VPN Connection with IPSec.

```
let manager: NEVPNManager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager()

let p = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()

p.serverAddress = config["vpn_ap"].stringValue
p.username = config["id"].stringValue
p.passwordReference = config["secret"].stringValue.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.SharedSecret
p.sharedSecretReference = config["psk"].stringValue.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
p.disconnectOnSleep = false

manager.`protocol` = p
manager.enabled = true

manager.saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler { error in
    if let e = error{
        print("error: " + e.description)
    }
    return
}

do{
 try manager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

But the NEVPNManager contains always the default values. The connection status is invalid.
For example:

```
print("enabled: " + manager.enabled.description ) // is false!
```

What do I wrong with this object? The fields are public, there are no compiler warnings. Who can help?

Comment: `manager.\`protocol\` = p` Is this a typo in the question? What are those tick marks?

Comment: protocol is a keyword, therefore it have to be quoted by backticks. This var name is deprecated, in 10.11 it is called protcolConfiguration. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html